# Can I create a Windows shortcut to a web-based file that immediately downloads and opens the file when clicked, with no browser?

Tags: windows, shortcut-file

I've created a self-extracting archive that users of my software can download and run.  It works great from a browser, but I would like to create a shortcut on the desktop that points to my archive and runs it when invoked.

Currently, if I create a shortcut to "http://something.com/myfile.exe", it brings up a browser with the .exe file downloaded, and then the user has to click on the downloaded file to run it, and the browser remains open.  If a browser must be involved, I would like it to automatically open the downloaded file and terminate.  Is that possible?

Comment: This sort of question should be asked on [su] instead, as it's not programming rleated. With that being said, Windows shortcuts only access the web through a browser. It's what's registered to handle the `http://` and `https://` protocols. In addition, such behavior would  raise havok with any reasonably effective AV/malware detection software and any halfway competent IT staff, and any halfway intelligent networking staff would block the attempt to download an .exe without explicit consent by an authorized (privileged) user.

Comment: Well, Click-Once and JNLP have been doing it for years.  Now those technologies are falling out of favor, but we still need users to be able to install and run our applications without an admin account.

Answer (score 0):

You need a program that downloads the file. It can be browser or any other application, like **curl** or **wget**. But something has to send a `HTTP GET` request to the file on that web server.

So, you can utilize Powershell for that requirement. On the shortcut just set the target as:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -Command { Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://something.com/myfile.exe" -OutFile "C:\myfile.exe"}
```

Beware that most of the time that file could be caught by an antimalware whether it is malicious or not. That is a suspicious attempt which you are doing.